# How to calculate number lines required for text

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I know this is going to be a stupid daft simple question but I'm going round in circles.

I have several strings which i want displaying in a uitableview. Some of these strings are very long. I have previously asked how to calculate the cell height, and choose the following answer:

```
- (CGFloat)cellHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellString = <YOUR MODEL OBJECT>;

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f] };
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                                               initWithString: cellString
                                               attributes:attributes];

    CGFloat width = self.tableView.frame.size.width - 32.0f;

    CGRect frame = [attributedString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];

    // Add some extra padding to the height    
    CGFloat height = frame.size.height + 16.0f;

    return ceil(height);
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [self cellHeightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

how can I get the number of lines required in the uitableview to display the strings.

Comment: Do you really want the number of lines or just the total height of the text?

Comment: If your goal is to set the appropriate numberOfLines property, note that you can just set it to 0, and it will scale automatically. If that's not the case, you can divide the text height for the label's lineHeight.

Comment: @andreamazz not if you've changed the paragraph style - he's using `NSAttributedString` so if he did that it would no longer work.

Comment: i did not realise that setting numberOfLines number to zero automatically calculated it for me. Setting it to zero has done exactly what i wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to actually calculate a  cell height is to use a prototype cell for calculating the height.

Add a `property` to your interface extension:

```
@interface TableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) TableViewCell *prototypeCell;

@end
```

Then lazily load it:

```
- (TableViewCell *)prototypeCell
{
  if (!_prototypeCell)
  {
    _prototypeCell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Prototype"];
  }
  return _prototypeCell;
}
```

Change your `-[tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]` method to use a `-[configureCell:forRowAtIndexPath:]` type pattern:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellId" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self configureCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

-(void)configureCell:(TableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Set up you cell from your model
}
```

Now use this method to setup your prototype and then use the height of that for `-[tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:]`:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  [self configureCell:self.prototypeCell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  [self.prototypeCell layoutIfNeeded];

  CGSize size = [self.prototypeCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
  return ceil(size.height);
}
```